# Ambiguous reference with generic class

Tags: c#

I have an object in two distinct namespace witch i need in an other class :

```
public class MyObject<T>
```

I want to do something like

```
using MyObject = MyNameSpace1.MyObject;
```

But it does not work.

How can I do?